How to propagate MDC in spring cloud gateway
I am using Spring Cloud gateway and in my logback file I am using MDC like to log username to every log line.
<property name="LOG_PATTERN"
          value="%d [TRACE_ID: %X{traceId}] [SPAN_ID: %X{spanId}] [LOGIN: %X{username}] %-4p: %c. %m%n"/>

I tried with ContextRegistry but it doesn't seem to work.
    ContextRegistry.getInstance()
        .registerThreadLocalAccessor("username",
                () -> MDC.get("username"),
                value -> MDC.put("username", value),
                () -> MDC.remove("username"));

    Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();

